# Cognos Analytics - save weekly reports to local drive

Tags: cognos, cognos-bi, cognos-11

In the current situation weekly scheduled reports are saved to the Cognos server. However, I was asked if there is a way to save them to a local network drive. Is this possible (documentation on this issue will help too)? We're using Cognos Analytics 11.0.13 on-premise.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You didn't state whether you have Cognos installed on-prem or are using the IBM cloud.  Different environments pose different problems.

Comment: Ah, I was not aware of that. It is an on-prem installation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  There are two ways.

Using Archive Location File System Root:

- Within the Archive Location File System Root (in Configuration), a folder is created for a user or business unit to write to.  In my case (on MS Windows) I use a junction pointing to their folder on the network.
- In Define File System Locations (in Cognos Administration), I configure an alias to the folder and apply permissions for certain users, groups, or roles to use (write to) that alias.
- Users schedule or use "run as" to get their reports to run and write output to their location.

Using CM.OutPutLocation and CM.OutputScript:

- For the folder or report in Cognos, apply permissions for certain users, groups, or  roles to create versions.  (write or full permission?)
- Users schedule or use "run as" to save their report output as a version of the report.
- Cognos saves a copy to the folder defined in CM.OutPutLocation (in Cognos Administration).
- The script defined in CM.OutputScript runs.  This script can:

  - Identify which file was just created.
  - Read the description (xml) file to determine the report path.
  - If the report path matches a specific pattern or value, do something (like copy it to the subfolder/junction and rename it to something meaningful like the report name).
  - Delete the original output file.

The second option seems like more coding, but far more flexible.  It must be a .bat file, but that can call anything (PowerShell, Windows Scripting Host, executable) to do the actual work, so a thorough knowledge batch programming isn't even needed.

Answer (score 0):

Down the line, if the requirement changes from save to local file system and becomes save to cloud.  There is also this functionality which has been added:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEP7J_11.1.0/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.ag_manage.doc/t_ca_manage_cloud_storage_add_location.html